# make keyframe repeat when js function outputs new text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this button which triggers a js function that outputs different strings in a div in my HTML document.

I applied a keyframe animation to this div buy I want it to be triggeed everytime the text in the div changes (basically everytime I press the button).

Edit: To be more clear, I just want the animation I applied to my text in the div to be triggered everytime I press the button. The button has a cooldown longer than the animation duration, so you shouldn't worry about what happens if the button is clicked during the animation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div {
        position: relative;
        animation: anim 1s infinite linear;
      }

      @keyframes anim {
        from {
          top: 0px;
        }
        to {
          top: 100px;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="btn">
      <p>this button triggers a js function</p>
    </button>
    <div id="output">Js output is shown here</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

obviusly the animations should not be infinite in the final version, but should happen everytime I press the button.

Comment: define the animation based upon a css class. when you want to play the animation, remove the class and add it  back to the element (see classList.remove and classList.add)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It makes it much easier to give a non-guessed-at answer. Also could you describe what you want to happen if the animation is only part way through when the user clicks the button again.